# passing methods working with arrays to main

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

If I have a method that finds the greatest integer in an array.  How do I pass the result back to main?

```
public static int maxNumber(int[] Array) {
   int maxNumber = Array[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < Array.length; i++) {
      if (List[i] > maxNumber) {
         maxNumber = Array[i]; 
      }
      return maxNumber;
   }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using java

Comment: your tags say c# just fyi.

Comment: @shockawave123 sorry, that was my edit. There was originally no language tag and it looked like c# to me.

Comment: You returning a value. Where do you call this method?

Comment: The `return` statement is inside of the `for` loop, so it will always return the first element. take it to the last line of the function

Comment: List doesnt exist. I assume you meant Array. Anyways Array doesnt look like a proper variable name. Use lowercase for variables so it doesnt look as a class name

Answer (score 2):

Return the result outside the loop, it should be this way

```
public static int maxNumber(int[] Array)
{
     int maxNumber = Array[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < Array.length; i++)
     {
         if (List[i] > maxNumber)
         {
             maxNumber = Array[i];
         }
     }
     return maxNumber;
}
```

if you want to get the number as output, call like this

```
   int max = maxNumber(yourArray);
```

Comment: Do I just type maxNumber into my main to get output?                                                                                                                
    public static void main(String[] args){                                            
     maxNumber();      }

Comment: @cruiser check the above answer